# Authentication Issue when accesing Reporting Service

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, iis-7.5, reportingservices-2005

Well, I already tried a lot of stuff to solve this issue, but none did.

I developed a Reporting Service (2005) and deployed it.

This report will be used by everyone who access a website (it's a internet site, so, won't be accessed by intranet) developed on the framework 3.5 (but I think the framework's version is not the source of the problem).

When the user clicks on the button to download the .pdf which the Reporting automatically generates (the end-user never sees the html version of the Report), it asks for windows credentials.

If the user enters a valid credential (and this credential must be a valid credential on the server which the Reporting Service is deployed), the .pdf is obviously downloaded.

But this can't happen. The end-user must download the .pdf directly, without asking for credentials. Afterall, he doesn't even have the credentials.

```
Response.Redirect("http://MyServer/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fReportLuiza%2fReportContract&rs:Format=PDF&NMB_CONTRACT=" + txtNmbContractReport.Text);
```

The code snippet above, shows the first version of my code when the user clicks the button. This one propmts for the Windows credentials.

I already tried to change on IIS the Authentication of the virtual directory ReportServer, but the only one which works is the Windows Credentials. The other ones doesn't even let me open the virtual directory of the Report or the Report Manager's virtual directory.

When I tried to change it to *Anonymous Authentication* he couldn't access the DataBase. Then I choose the option to **Credentials stored securely on the report server**. Still doesn't work.

The physical directory of my ReportServer virtual directory points to the reporting server folder on the Hard Disk (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.5\Reporting Services\ReportServer). I moved the same folder to my wwwroot directory.
Didn't work. The virtual directory didn't even open. Then I read this could be a problem because I had the same name on two folders (one in C: and other in wwwroot). So I changed the name of the one in wwwroot. Same issue of the DataBase connection couldn't be done.
I returned the physical path to C:

Below, is the second version of my button's event code:

```
ReportExecutionService rs = new ReportExecutionService();
        rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        rs.Url = "http://MyServer/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx";

        // Render arguments
        byte[] result = null;
        string reportPath = "/ReportLuiza/ReportContract";
        string format = "PDF";

        // Prepare report parameter.
        ParameterValue[] parameters = new ParameterValue[1];
        parameters[0] = new ParameterValue();
        parameters[0].Name = "NMB_CONTRACT";
        parameters[0].Value = txtNmbContractReport.Text;

        string encoding;
        string mimeType;
        string extension;
        Warning[] warnings = null;
        string[] streamIDs = null;

        ExecutionInfo execInfo = new ExecutionInfo();
        ExecutionHeader execHeader = new ExecutionHeader();

        rs.ExecutionHeaderValue = execHeader;

        execInfo = rs.LoadReport(reportPath, null);

        rs.SetExecutionParameters(parameters, "pt-br");
        String SessionId = rs.ExecutionHeaderValue.ExecutionID;

        try
        {
            result = rs.Render(format, null, out extension, out encoding, out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIDs);

            execInfo = rs.GetExecutionInfo();
        }
        catch (SoapException se)
        {
            ShowMessage(se.Detail.OuterXml);
        }

        // Write the contents of the report to an pdf file.
        try
        {
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"c:\report.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                stream.Write(result, 0, result.Length);
                stream.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ShowMessage(ex.Message);
        }
```

For this code, I had to add a WebReference to the .asmx file mentioned in it.

When I'm debugging (on Visual Studio 2010), the code above works fine, doesn't asking for credentials (unfortunately, it doesn't prompt the option to open, save or cancel de file download. But this is another problem, no need to worry with it now) and save the file on C:.

When published, the code doesn't work. An erros says: *The permission granted to user **'IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0'** are insuficient for performing this operation*. So I added to the Reporting Service's users this user. When I tried again, the error is: *Login failed for user **IISAPPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0**. Cannot create a connection to data source 'MyDataSourceName'*.

Both Report and WebSite are deployed/published on the same server with a IIS 7.5 version.

Summarizing: I need a solution where there is no credential prompt, and the user can choose where it wants to save the .pdf file.

Any help will be appreciated.

If you need more information to help me, just ask.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to create a new *App Pool* with an account that has the rights to access your restricted resources and then assign your web application to it.

Comment: Hello George. Works perfectly. Sorry if I'm bothering you too much, but... do you have a solution to prompt the download box (with the options OPEN, SAVE and CANCEL)? I've searched and I found nothing that solves the problem with websites, just with Windows Forms. Anyway, I'm very glad for your help.

Comment: @Fernando Glad it helped.  If you have another question, please post it as a new question and I as well as others would be glad to help.